# Unity - Drag with right mouse button?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a build in Unity 2019.4.12f1 and need to drag an object with Right Mouse button.
My C# skills are very limited, so far but i try.

This scripts is my attempt to be able to rotate a gameobject by holding right mouse button down and dragging ingame.

But it is wrong.
Can anyone help me correct it?´

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouseM : MonoBehaviour
{
     bool dragging = false;

     void Start()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            dragging = true;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            yourOnMouseDownFunction();
            dragging = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            yourOnMouseUpFunction();
            dragging = false;
        }

        if (dragging)
        {
            yourOnMouseDragFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood that You need to Drag Object in 3d World so Here is my Code just create new Script and attach to Object You Want to Drag it

> Your Object that You need to Drag it should has a collider

```
using UnityEngine;
public class DragableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 mOffset;
    private float mZCoord;

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        transform.position = GetMouseWorldPos() + mOffset;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        mZCoord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
        mOffset = transform.position - GetMouseWorldPos();
    }

    private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPos()
    {
        Vector3 mosePoint = Input.mousePosition;
        mosePoint.z = mZCoord;
        var result = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mosePoint);
        return result;
    }
}
```

you can try it by adding it to sphere or cube and if you use custom shape you should insure that the collider is in suitable size or has a meshcollier
[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAwxl.png)

**EDIT**

```
using UnityEngine;
public class DragableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isMouseDragging;
    private Vector3 screenPosition;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private GameObject target;

    GameObject ReturnClickedObject(out RaycastHit hit)
    {
        GameObject targetObject = null;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, out hit))
        {
            targetObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
        return targetObject;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            target = ReturnClickedObject(out hitInfo);
            if (target != null)
            {
                    isMouseDragging = true;
                    Debug.Log("our target position :" + target.transform.position);
                    //Here we Convert world position to screen position.
                    screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(target.transform.position);
                offset = target.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPosition.z));
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            isMouseDragging = false;
        }

        if (isMouseDragging)
        {
            //tracking mouse position.
            Vector3 currentScreenSpace = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPosition.z);

            //convert screen position to world position with offset changes.
            Vector3 currentPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(currentScreenSpace) + offset;

            //It will update target gameobject's current postion.
            target.transform.position = currentPosition;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is for left mouse button.
The problem is that i need it for RIGHT mouse button.

OnMouseDrag only works with Left mouse btn.

Comment: Yes I have changed Completely to do this, Also You Can use old Idea with Unity Event System to do same Operation

Comment: Great script Sir.
I works like a charm.

Sorry for the late answer, but was not at work during weekend.
I the meantime i got another script to work also.

I thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Input.GetMouseButton method, this should return a value depending on if the button is held pressed.

Comment: I do that in my script above, but i am doing something wrong?

Comment: You use the GetMouseButtonDown method, not the GetMouseButton method. I think the GetMouseButton should return the "is-button-down" information not only in the frame that you click the button, but also across other frames. Do the methods behave the same in your case?

Comment: Every single drag move script i find uses LEFT mouse btn and OnMouseDrag

Comment: What is the compiler error you get? Try getting this working.

Comment: Just the standard "All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!" and no help in the console.

I think the whole script needs rewriting.

Comment: Don't you use an IDE for your scripts? E.g. with Visual Studio, you will be shown the exact compilation error

Comment: Actually i think the compiler error was partly due to me having other scripts that did not work in my asset folder.

Comment: I got the script from Hassan Omar to work, and another one i posted below too.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This one works too, if someone needs in the future.
This is for rotate though.
Sorry, i dont know why it wont let me post as code, so i post an image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbKZw.jpg)